# Arduino transmitter and receiver

Tags: arduino-uno

hi I am using Arduino transmitter and receiver it works properly with sending and receiving username and password but I would include to check the username if its true open the led , I added this in the code but it seems that the code ignoring it ( the last part) as well as I want it to take the password and username at the same time

this is the recover code

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>//include radioHead ASK library 
#include <SPI.h> // include dependant SPI libray

 RH_ASK rf_driver; // create ASK object
int ledon = 13;
String userid;
String password;
 //RH_ASK ID1; // create ASK object
//RH_ASK pass1; // create ASK object

void setup() {

  rf_driver.init(); //initialize ASK object 


  Serial.begin(9600); //setup serial monitor to 9600

  //if(!rf_driver.init())
       //Serial.print("init failed");      
}

void loop() {

  // set buffer to size of expected message 
  uint8_t buf[9];  
  uint8_t buflen =sizeof(buf);

  //check if recevied packet is correct size
  if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))
  {
    int i;
    // message received with valid checksum 
    Serial.print("id: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);
      userid =(char*)buf;
        Serial.println(userid);

  }

delay(5000);

   uint8_t buf2[8];  
  uint8_t buflen2 = sizeof(buf2);

   if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))

  {

    int i;
    // message received with valid checksum 
    Serial.print("password: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);
      password = (char*)buf;
      Serial.println(password);

  }
  delay(5000);

while ( userid =="A00034732" && password == "123456789"){
digitalWrite(ledon, HIGH);
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(ledon, LOW);

}
}
```

transmitter code ----

```
//Include RadioHead Amplitidue shift keying library 
#include <RH_ASK.h>
// Include dependatnt ISP library 
#include <SPI.h>

//create Ampitude shift keying object 
RH_ASK rf_driver;


void setup() {
 // intialize ASK objct
rf_driver.init();

Serial.begin(9600);

  //if(!rf_driver.init())
      //Serial.print("init failed");

}

void loop() 
{

  const char *pass= "123456789";
rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)pass, strlen(pass));
rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
delay(5000);

const char *ID= "A00034732";

rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)ID, strlen(ID));
rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
delay(5000);

//const char *pass= "12345678";
//rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)pass, strlen(pass));
//rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
//delay(5000);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing strings - you're comparing addresses of strings.  Use [`strcmp()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).

```
while ( 
    (strcmp(userid, "A00034732") == 0) && 
    (strcmp(password, "123456789") == 0)
) {
```

Comment: I want to convert it to integer